# angular2 with Visual Studio Code browser sync working only after save

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, browser-sync

I went through Angular2 setup with Visual Studio Code via https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

which worked very nicely. However I expected by typing changes in the html it should be automatically visible in the browser via Browser Sync, while I need to save the file in order to get the browser refresh new text.

Is it how it is expected to work and if not how would I change the settings?

Comment: I have been working with angular 2 for almost a year now and I have always had to save in order for browser sync to take

Comment: I was playing with ng2 apx. a year or so ago, and I somehow recall it was refreshing on the go, but I cannot be sure. I could turn on the autosave feature to have that available, but this likely disables e.g undoing etc. so would not be my fav. option (I thought angular or its linked setup packages can make this sort of projection without doing acual save to the file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-save does not affect the undo/redo stack in vscode, and if it does then it is a bug that the team will fix, so you can safely use that to get immediate feedback via browsersync.